# Unity - "New" custom class instance isn't separated from other instance

Tags: class, unity-game-engine, inventory

**Solved myself, I'm silly**

**Solved myself, I'm silly**

**Solved myself, I'm silly**

See my answer below.

Having an issue with classes here, not sure of the cause.

In my scene I have 2 GameObjects being instantiated from the same prefab. Each has an InventoryManager script attached, and in this script I'm creating a new instance of a class called Inventory using inside InventoryManager:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class InventoryManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Inventory inventory;
    private ItemDatabase itemDatabase;

    void Start () 
    {
        inventory = new Inventory (9);
    }
}
```

But for whatever reason, any of the List's values in my Inventory class is being shared between both of the instantiated GameObjects.

Here's a peak of the inventory class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class Inventory
{
    public int ID;
    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
    public int maxSize;

    public static int inventoryCount;

    public Inventory(int size)
    {
        ID = inventoryCount;
        inventoryCount++;
        maxSize = size;
    }
}
```

Basically, when I add a new thing into

```
gameobject1.GetComponent<InventoryManager>().inventory.Add(item1);
```

(The add method does exist, it's a bit long so i'll only post it if requested)

It will also show up in gameobject2's inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I feel like a total goof, and of course I would solve the issue after posting it.

Basically, I made the very, very silly mistake of taking what my UI was displaying at face value, instead of using the inspector to see what was ACTUALLY in the inventory.

The issue was with my UI showing the wrong stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing that `inventoryCount` is also going up on your second game object? If that's your indicator that there is an object in gameobject2's `items` variable that's not the case. `inventoryCount` is static and will be the same across all instances of `Inventory`. Try removing the `static` keyword from `inventoryCount`

Comment: Hi, `inventoryCount` is supposed to be static, as it should count all the inventory instances already created, so I can give them a unique incremental ID, as seen in the constructor. I did notice that the ID of each object is different and working. So the issue must lie within the list somewhere.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of in that case is that the prefabing system is messing with you. Are you instantiating the objects in code or are you dragging them into the scene? If you are dragging them in try decoupling them from the prefab first. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/11138/breaking-a-prefab-connection.html

Comment: Hey, I solved the issue. Basically I was really stupid and trusted what my UI was showing me. When I checked the inspector everything was working as it should. The issue was within the UI.

Comment: I saw your answer below. Glad you fixed it! Update your OP and I guess mark this as closed :)

Comment: Cheers! I've edited the OP but I cannot close the thread yet as I answered my own question and I must wait 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look on your existing code:

```
gameobject1.GetComponent<InventoryManager>().inventory.Add(item1);
```

In above the `inventory`is not any memeber of your `InventoryManager` class and `GetComponent` itself return an instance of its class. I believe you want to add an item in the `List<Item>` property. So the code should be like below:

```
gameobject1.GetComponent<InventoryManager>().Items.Add(item1);
```

**Edit:**

As per the updated question, the proposed solution would be

```
gameobject1.GetComponent<InventoryManager>().inventory.Items.Add(item1);
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Hi, sorry. The class I've posted above isn't `InventoryManager`, but the `Inventory` class. I will edit the OP so this is more clear.